# How to say “worthless” in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage

> Someone that I care about doesn't pay attention to me, and makes me feel worthless.

What is the best word to define that kind of word "worthless" in French?

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu dire qu'une personne peut *se sentir nulle*.

Comment: Lol if you feel "worthless" because of somebody else's action then that's pretty bad. The essence of living is being independent and always relying on one's own, regardless of how any other person is acting. I know these are not necessarily your own words, just saying.

Answer (score 6):

Pour cette personne je suis quelqu'un *sans intérêt* (elle ne voit rien d'intéressant à faire avec moi) et je me sens alors *déprécié*, *dévalorisé*.

Plus familièrement je pourrais me dire que je suis *un minable, un loser* (anglicisme, écrit aussi *looser*, prononcé 'louzeur'), *un pauvre type, un moins que rien*.

Comment: La question n'est pas à propos de ce que l'autre ressent, mais de ce que l'on ressent soi-même.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai pris note de votre remarque et modifié le point de vue exprimé.

Answer (score 6):

on peut aussi dire *inutile* ou *insignifiant*.

Comment: *Insignifiant* est parfait dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom in French meaning that you feel worthless is to say that you feel *moins que rien* (lit. *less than nothing*). This group of words can be used as a as an emotion (a way you can feel) or a noun (a worthless person). In the latter case you would say that you feel like a worthless person, *comme un moins que rien.*

> Someone that I care for doesn't pay attention to me and makes me feel worthless.

Translates to:

> Quelqu'un que j'apprécie ne porte pas attention à moi et me fait me sentir moins que rien.

OR

> Quelqu'un que j'apprécie ne porte pas attention à moi et me fait me sentir comme un moins que rien.

Answer (score 1):

Également *quelqu'un qui n'en vaut pas la peine.*

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette pharase, "worthless" pourrait se traduire par : Cette personne me fait sentir comme un bon à rien (masculin) ou comme une bonne  à rien (féminin).

Answer (score 0):

On peut dire que quelqu'un *est nul* ou bien qu'on *se sent nul*.

Regardez un peu les définitions de [l'Internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/nul/#definition).

Le mot *nul* signifie:

- qui équivaut à rien
- sans aucune valeur

J'estime ces deux significations très proches de celle en anglais.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that someone "*vaut rien*" which is more or less the literal translation of "*worthless*" :

> Il ne connaît même pas les bases du métier, il ne vaut rien!
>
> He does not even know the basics of the job, he is worthless.

I your case, "*I feel worthless*" would be something like "*J'ai l'impression que je vaux rien*" or "*J'ai l'impression de ne valoir rien*".